# Non-numerical values for integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, warning-messages

I am trying to solve the following integral numerically

```
SEND[d_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[NIntegrate[k ((1/\[Tau]) Exp[-2 k d])/((1/\[Tau])^2 + (\[Omega]+k Cos[\[Theta]]+k Sin[\[Theta]])^2), {k,0,Infinity}], {\[Theta],0,2\[Pi]}]
```

but Mathematica keeps giving me the error

[image]

I have tried everything I could find, e.g., finite integration interval, use of ?NumericQ. Any clue? Thanks

Comment: Have you defined tau?

Comment: setting $\tau=1$

Comment: Please update your post, not everyone is reading comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done as follows.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; 
f[\[Theta]_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, \[Omega]_?NumericQ, \[Tau]_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[k ((1/\[Tau]) Exp[-2 k d])/((1/\[Tau])^2 + (\[Omega] + 
k Cos[\[Theta]] + k Sin[\[Theta]])^2), {k, 0, Infinity}]
f[Pi/4, 1, Pi/3, 2]
```

> `0.0281453`

```
g[d_?NumericQ, \[Omega]_?NumericQ, \[Tau]_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[f[\[Theta], d, \[Omega], \[Tau]], {\[Theta], 0, 2 *Pi}]
g[4, 1, 1]
```

> `0.050794`

Addition

```
SEND[d_?NumericQ, \[Omega]_?NumericQ, \[Tau]_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[NIntegrate[ k ((1/\[Tau]) Exp[-2 k d])/((1/\[Tau])^2 + (\[Omega] +  k Cos[\[Theta]] + k Sin[\[Theta]])^2), {k, 0, 
Infinity}], {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
SEND[4, 1, 1]
```

> `0.050794`

also works, but perfoms the same warning as yours.

Comment: Thank you. That works indeed. However, if I ask for g[10^{-3},1,1] I still encounter an issue: "NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small." Any idea of how to overcome that? I tried to increase MaxPoints and Workingprecisioin, but it did not work.

Comment: `g[10^{-3},1,1]` produces `2218.03` and a warning (not an error) quoted by you.

Comment: right, you are correct. but the error states about the inaccuracy of the value: 

"NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in \[Theta] near {\[Theta]} = {5.49769}. NIntegrate obtained 2214.5754409669808` and 30.909327582704197` for the integral and error estimates."

Comment: You are right.: I overlooked an error communication.The code `g[d_?NumericQ, \[Omega]_?NumericQ, \[Tau]_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[f[\[Theta], d, \[Omega], \[Tau]], {\[Theta], 0, 2 *Pi}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 4, PrecisionGoal -> 4, MaxRecursion -> 30]
g[10^-3, 1, 1]` produces `2218.3` and only a warning.